# C#: dynamic variable not binding as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic

I have an entity in my database which has a corresponding "history" entity. The data held in both entities is fundamentally the same; the "history" table is used to track changes in this data over time, with the main table containing only the latest data.

There are places in my C# code where I am needing to access a property that could come from either an instance of the primary entity or the "history" entity. For example, both entities have a "SalesPrice" property, and I'd like to be able to write single statements using this property that will work for either entity type.

The C# "dynamic" keyword seems like it should enable this. For example, if we assume *MethodWithDynamicReturnType()* is declared as returning dynamic, and, at runtime, will return either an instance of the main entity or the history entity, then I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
 dynamic d;
 d=MethodWithDynamicReturnType();
 Console.WriteLine(d.SalesPrice.ToString());
```

But I got an exception ("Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"). So, I tried to make things just a bit more explicit for the runtime:

```
 Main_Entity m;
 History_Entity h;
 MethodThatWillFillOneOutParameterOnly(out m, out h);
 dynamic d;
 if(h!=null){d=h;}else{d=m;}
 Console.WriteLine(d.SalesPrice.ToString());
```

This didn't prevent the exception. Interestingly, though, if I cast variable "d" to "Main_Entity" or "History_Entity," as appropriate, my code works... but isn't avoiding that cast the whole point of "dynamic?"

Either I've been completely misinformed about "dynamic," or, searching for other explanations, could Entity Framework perhaps be at fault? I do notice that the actual runtime value I'm assigning into "d" has a weird "proxy" class name, *not* the actual entity type name I'd prefer to see. Is that indicative of some sort indirection there that's keeping "dynamic" from serving its intended purpose?

Comment: Can you confirm that SalesPrice was not null when the error occurs?

Comment: Yes, GantTheWanderer, SalesPrice is not null. If it were null, I'd expect a simple "null reference exception" upon invoking .ToString(), but that's not what's happening. Really strange problem!

Comment: Actually if SalesPrice were null you would still get an error saying `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` I just tested it myself, I can provide the code if you are curious

Comment: Are you using an entity framework like NHibernate?  I have seen NHibernate create proxy classes for entities.  If this is happening, is it possible for the property SalesPrice to not exist with the same name?

Comment: @GantTheWandered, yes, I'm pretty sure you're close to the answer. I'm using EF (Microsoft's answer to NHibernate). In the debugger, the proxy class definitely has all the right members. The problem is that my dynamic variable ends up having type "object" at runtime. Somewhere between object creation and the point where I assign it into my "dynamic" variable, it's getting cast to "Object" or otherwise stripped of its type information. Has to be EF, I guess.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, if you  set `ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled` to false. (stopping fancy features like lazy loading and change tracking.) do you have the same outcome?

Comment: 'Somewhere between object creation and the point where I assign it into my "dynamic" variable, it's getting cast to "Object" or otherwise stripped of its type information'. That would at least happen at the time when you assign to `dynamic` because `dynamic` **is** `object` along with an indication to the compiler that that `object` should have dynamic binding done on it rather than compile-time.